# Fastest lxml interface for parsing small, rigidly structured XML files

Tags: xml, python-3.x, performance, xslt, lxml

I have an xml document with the following structure which I am looking to parse:

```
<base>
  <intermediate>
    <element>
      <field1>some_text</field2>
      <field2>more_text</field2>
    </element>
    # <element> repeated about 2000 times
  </intermediate>
</base>
```

My first approach was to use lxml's xslt interface to transform this into CSV and then read this csv into python lists.

After the performance was not quite what I was hoping for, I thought I would give the following a try:

```
for intermediate in root.xpath('./intermediate'):
    for element in index.xpath('./element[field2/text()]'):
        field1 = element.xpath('field1/text()')[0]
        field2 = element.xpath('field2/text()')[0]
```

That turned out to be much slower. - Which is not that much of a surprise.

Am I using lxml in the optimal way possible, though? It is so feature-rich that I cannot be sure that I have not chosen a poor interface for my given problem.

---

**Edit 1: Results of benchmarking**

- Solution 1: Python-looping tree traversal (as in OP) - 77.9ms
- Solution 2: iterparse - 11.4ms
- Solution 3: xml parsing & xslt (NO csv parsing) - 11.9ms
- Solution 4: cython linked SAX parser in C with libxml2 (file read in python) - 2.33ms

Code used for xslt:

```
xml = lxml.etree.parse('my_xml_file.xml')
xsl = lxml.etree.parse("my_xsl_file.xsl")
transformer = lxml.etree.XSLT(xsl)    
result = transformer(xml)
csv_data = str(result)
```

XSL used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/base">
        <xsl:text>field1|field2&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='intermediate/element[field2/text()]'/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <xsl:value-of select="field1"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="field2"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would guess that using `iterparse` with `tag=element` suffices and performs well, I am not quite sure which result structure you want (list of lists or list of tuples) and where that condition `./element[field2/text()]` comes from, it is not clear from your sample input.

Comment: ARF, where can I learn about "Solution 4: cython linked SAX parser in C with libxml2 (file read in python)" ? Is it worth learning for the faster performance?

Comment: @CPLTarun Sorry, I do not seem to have the code any longer. Cython is a way of writing code that looks like python that gets compiled into C-code (and hence have C-speed). What I did was basically to write a SAX parser using lxml2 in C. (See lxml2 docs for how to use it and C code examples.) I just did not use C language to interface to lxml2 but cython. The program logic is the same, just the language is different. You will need to refer to the cython docs on how to use it. - But really: This solution is practically pointless. The time you will need to invest to learn is not worth it.

Comment: @CPLTarun I found the code after all. See the answer. As it is, it is not really useable. But it should give you a starting point if you think the effort is worth it. I decided the increase in speed was not worth the effort. My bottleneck was not really xml parsing but downstream data processing. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following parses the XML file iteratively:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

with open("input.xml", "rb") as f:
    context = ET.iterparse(f)
    for action, elem in context:
        if elem.tag == "field1":
            field1 = elem.text

        if elem.tag == "field2":
            field2 = elem.text

        if elem.tag == "element":
            print(field1, field2)
            field1 = None
            field2 = None
```

Here lxml works in an event-based manner. Every time an end element (`</xyz>`) is encountered, an `end` event is generated and processed by the `for` loop.

Depending on which element has ended, variables `field1` and `field2` are being set. The implicit assumption here is that `<field1>` and `<field2>` only occur inside `<element>` and that are not nested any further.

If these things are guaranteed, then by the time we encounter a closing `</element>`, the two variables contain the expected strings. If these things are not necessarily true, you need to maintain some sort of state during the iteration.

From within Python, this should be as fast as it gets, because it solely relies on parsing events as and when they occur, and does not use any XPath at all.

Comment: Thanks, this was almost 8x faster than the nested loop solution with xpath. Even marginally faster than xslt alone (without the csv parsing step). I am wondering if my xsl has problems. My gut instinct was that xslt should be faster than python looping... Would you mind taking a look at my updated question to rule out that I made some blunder in my comparison?

Comment: The XSL stylesheet is looking good, I would not have done it any differently. Here's my guess: Internally XSLT uses XPath for everything (i.e. all "match" and "select" attributes), so it's probably faster by virtue of being compiled C code, but it's also doing a lot more work because it's much more generalized (plus there is an extra step of parsing the stylesheet itself, which Python has not to do, because there all the code is already parsed when it runs).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `iterparse`:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def parse_xml(file_name, tag_name):
    for event, element in ET.iterparse(file_name, tag = tag_name):
        if (element.xpath('field2/text()')):
            yield (element.find('field1').text, element.find('field2').text)

result = [tuple for tuple in parse_xml('input-file.xml', 'element')]

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed much faster. Benchmarking in OP if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to document option 4 in OP for @CPLTarun.

Note this is not production-ready code. This was just a quickly hacked benchmark. The code probably has bugs. Also, it does not even make the read data accessible from python, it just keeps it in cython variables that keep being overwritten. - This code is not intended to be useful but to provide a lower bound for the runtime of fully fleshed-out code.

I might have copied the bones of this code from somebody else. If the code is yours, let me know and I will credit you.

The following is code from a jupyter notebook. Each new cell is denoted with `#%%`:

```py
#%%
%load_ext cython

#%% cython SAX parser
%%cython
# distutils: include_dirs = <your liblxml2 include directory>
# distutils: libraries = libxml2
# distutils: library_dirs = <your liblxml2 lib directory>

from lxml.includes.xmlparser cimport (xmlParserCtxt, xmlSAXHandler, 
        xmlCreatePushParserCtxt, xmlParseChunk, xmlFreeParserCtxt, xmlCleanupParser,         
        XML_SAX2_MAGIC, xmlCtxtResetPush,
        startElementNsSAX2Func, endElementNsSAX2Func, charactersSAXFunc)
from libc.string cimport memset, memcpy, strcmp
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from lxml.includes.tree cimport const_xmlChar

cdef xmlParserCtxt* c_ctxt

cpdef void init_parser():
    global c_ctxt
    cdef xmlSAXHandler SAXHander

    memset(&SAXHander, 0, sizeof(xmlSAXHandler))
    SAXHander.initialized = XML_SAX2_MAGIC
    SAXHander.startElementNs = <startElementNsSAX2Func>OnStartElementNs
    SAXHander.endElementNs = <endElementNsSAX2Func>OnEndElementNs
    SAXHander.characters = <charactersSAXFunc>_handleSaxData

    c_ctxt = xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(&SAXHander, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL)

cpdef void parse_chunk(char* chars):
    global c_ctxt
    xmlParseChunk(c_ctxt, chars, len(chars), 0)
    xmlParseChunk(c_ctxt, NULL, 0, 1)
    xmlCtxtResetPush(c_ctxt, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)

cpdef void cleanup_parser():
    global c_ctxt
    xmlFreeParserCtxt(c_ctxt)
    xmlCleanupParser()


cdef char* field2 = NULL
cdef char* field1 = NULL
cdef char* element = NULL

cdef char* FIELD1 = b'field1'
cdef char* FIELD2 = b'field2'

cdef void OnStartElementNs(void* ctx,
                           const_xmlChar* localname,
                           const_xmlChar* prefix,
                           const_xmlChar* URI,
                           int nb_namespaces,
                           const_xmlChar** namespaces,
                           int nb_attributes,
                           int nb_defaulted,
                           const_xmlChar** attributes):
    c_ctxt = <xmlParserCtxt*>ctx

    global element

    if strcmp(<char*>localname, b'field2') == 0:
        element = FIELD2
    elif strcmp(<char*>localname, b'field1') == 0:
        element = FIELD1

cdef void OnEndElementNs(void* ctx,
                           const_xmlChar* localname,
                           const_xmlChar* prefix,
                           const_xmlChar* URI):
    c_ctxt = <xmlParserCtxt*>ctx
    global element
    if strcmp(<char*>localname, b'element') == 0:
        if strcmp(field2, b'') != 0:
            element= NULL
    else:
        element = NULL

cdef void _handleSaxData(void* ctxt, const_xmlChar* c_data, int data_len):
    # can only be called if parsing with a target
    global field2, field1
    if element == FIELD1:
        if field1 is not NULL:
            free(field1)
        field1 = <char*>malloc(sizeof(char) * (data_len+1))
        field1[data_len] = 0
        memcpy(field1, c_data, data_len)
    if element == FIELD2:
        if field2 is not NULL:
            free(field2)
        field2 = <char*>malloc(sizeof(char) * data_len+1)
        field2[data_len] = 0
        memcpy(field2, c_data, data_len)


#%% cython libxml
%%timeit -r20
with open('benchmark.xml', 'rb') as file:
    xml = file.read()
init_parser()
parse_chunk(xml)
cleanup_parser()
```

Note: you can save time by initialising the parser only once any processing multiple files before cleanup.